# Correct way to implement MVC with a complex model and without type checking and if-else chains

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller, architecture

I'm trying to write an application following the MVC architecture, more specifically the follwing approach: [image: following approach]

The controller:

```
public class Controller{
    ...

    public void newName() {
        model.setName(name);
    }

    public void newFoo() {
        model.setFoo(foo);
    }

    public void newBar() {
        model.setBar(bar);
    }
}
```

The model:

```
public class Model{
    ...

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        update();
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
        update();

    }    
    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
        update();
    }

    // Update implemented like this:
    private void update() {
        setChanged();
        // calls update(...) on observers
        notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

The view:

```
public class View{
    ...

    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        Model model = (Model) o;
        fieldName.setText(model.getName());
        fieldFoo.setText(model.getFoo());
        fieldBar.setText(model.getBar());
    }
}
```

My problem is that if I don't want to update the entire view at the same time, as in updating both name, foo and bar, in the view, I'll have to do type checking or create an if-else chain, to test which field was updated.

If I'd used listeners, I could implement a concrete method call for every field.

However, I feel that both these approaches break with good OOP and modifiability/loose coupling, and so on. What happens if I have 100 fields in the model? 100 Separate if's/methods?

So I suppose what I'm asking is, what is the best, in regard to OOP and modifiability, way to update only the required field in `update()`, without having to update everything?

Could I solve this with polymorphism?

*I excuse asking such a possibly broad question, but I've been struggling with this for a while, and I did not find any other threads that I felt could give me a good answer, so I thought I'd try making my own thread. I might not have found similar threads because I don't really know what to search for.*

Comment: So you can add 'property name' parameter to `update()` method. Of you could look closely into MVP and MVVM patterns which look closer to what you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use java.beans.PropertyChangeListener to notify updates to the view. Here, the PropertyChangeEvent passes the source, propertyName, oldValue and the newValue. If you want totally new classes, code similar to PropertyChangeListener and PropertyChangeEvent.
2. Make sure model and view follow a naming convention for the properties and access methods similar to JavaBeans naming convention.
3. Within the propertyChange() method of the view, get the propertyName which is available as a string, determine the view method (as a string) according to the naming convention, use Java reflection API to invoke the corresponding method of the view by passing the newValue as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I am a little off.

You could encapsulate all of your fields in a collection object with IDs. On the update call, the ID/IDs that need setting would be passed in. Then:

1. Search your collection object with the ID
2. Update that field by it's ID

This prevents you from having to update every field with old date, when only a few or even one field has been updated. And could even act as a sort of security layer!

It's a little of a far shot, but when you are dealing with hundreds of unique fields; it's bound to get a little ugly eventually.

Hope that offered a little inspiration...

Comment: That is one partial solution yes, however, it's still not quite what I'm looking for. +1 for being helpful!